# PC Display Is Noisy While Rendering

Tags: display, graphics-card, hdmi, vga, noise

I bought a GTX 1080 TI (EVGA SC2) on Ebay and I use it primarily for 3D rendering animations. This pretty much utilizes all of the resources of the GPU. Here's an example:

[image]

vs when it is idle, the "GPU load" section is 0%.

I have the card plugged into a monitor using an HDMI to VGA adapter like this picture:

[image]

where the HDMI side of the adapter goes into the HDMI port on the back of the graphics card:

[image]

and then I have another VGA cable going between the adapter and the monitor. I observed that while I am rendering, there is a fuzzy noise/static pattern that appears on the display. It is still usable, because it is fairly light and I can see everything underneath the static, but it is quite annoying. The noise disappears as soon as I stop the 3D render, and it appears instantly when I start the 3D render up.

If instead of using this adapter, I use an HDMI cable directly from the graphics card to the monitor, I do not see any noise. So I assume this is related to the fact that VGA is analog vs. HDMI being digital. **What I don't understand is if this is normal behavior I would expect to see. Is there something wrong with the graphics card that is causing this? Is there something wrong with the adapter? Or would you always expect to observe this on modern GPUs since they draw so much power?** I'm just trying to understand why I'm observing this.

Comment: It might be because the adapter introduces a delay, which causes a lag. VGA might not be fast enough.

Comment: @harrymc, then why would I only observe this while the 3D render is occurring but I don't observe it otherwise?

Comment: Possibly the 3D render does a lot of screen refreshes. (Only a theory, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

HDMI to VGA requires a converter with active electronics. That means that the converter needs power in order to do the conversion. HDMI [can supply a moderate amount of power](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28575/could-hdmi-be-potentially-used-as-a-power-supply-alternative-for-smartphones) to the electronics, but that power is not limitless, and has to be supplied by the graphics card, potentially from the PCIe slot but potentially from the graphics card itself.

It is possible that there is only just enough power being supplied to the converter. When the graphics card is not under load the voltage might be slightly higher and giving the converter slightly more power, under heavy load the power might "sag" slightly causing the converter to function less than optimally.

It is also possible that the multiple stages of power conversion on the graphics card that go from 12V down to the approximately 1V used by the GPU core, along with other voltages, are causing some interference on the 5V power line that is being used by the converter. Most voltage converters have a high switching frequency, but it is possible that some harmonic is down at frequencies that might be visible in the display.